# Don't know how to connect multiple MCP23017

Tags: pi-3, gpio, hardware, python-3

I need more pins on my raspberry pi 3 so that I can use it to manage the lights in my house. I am going to use relays and MCP23017. I need to know how to use 8 of the MCP23017 on my raspberry pi. If you can I also need to know how to use them in python to go in and out like normal.

Comment: I need help as much as i can get.

Comment: What do you mean by "help as much as possible"?.  The following posts in relay and mcp23017 might take you  hours to just skim through: (1) KY-019 2108/2019 posts by tlfong01 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158#p1323061,

You can also search in  rpi.org forum for as much more help as possible. Examples: (2) Search  "ky-019" "tlfong01"  to get 371 matches, (2) Search "mcp23017" "tlfong01" to get 178 matches.  Happy learning and making.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connect pin 12 SCL and pin 13 SDA in parallel to RPi pin 3 SCL & pin 5 SDA.

So the MCP23017 are daisy chained.

You can run up to eight in parallel by setting the A0/A1/A2 pins to a different 3-bit binary value on each MCP23017.